# Recursive directory reading

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm trying to recursively get all files and sub folders of a directory. Here is what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "dirent.h"
#include <io.h>

using namespace std;

void listDir(char *directory)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    if((dir = opendir (directory)) != NULL)
    {
        while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL)
        {
            if(strstr(ent->d_name,".") != NULL)
                cout<<ent->d_name<<endl;
            else
            {
                strcat(directory,ent->d_name);
                strcat(directory,"\\");
                strcat(directory,"\0");
                cout<<directory<<endl;
                cin.get();
                listDir(directory);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir (dir);
}

int main(int param, char **args)
{
    char *path = new char[];
    path = args[1];
    strcat(path, "\\");
    listDir(path);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I am using dirent (actually pretty cool, get it if you don't already) and when I recursively get the folders it seems to add on to the directory at the end of my sub folder. For example:

[image]

Downloads, Images, and Includes are all subfolders of my Jakes625 folder. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: what problem are you having?

Comment: this code doesn't even compile: this statement needs a size: ``char *path = new char[];`` why aren't you using c++ strings?

Comment: Why is this tagged C instead of C++?  You're using `#include <iostream>` so it must be C++, not C.

Comment: What is your question? What do you *want* the program to do instead of what it does now?

Comment: recursively list every single file in every subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void listDir(const string& path)
{
  DIR *dir;
  struct dirent *ent;

  if((dir = opendir (path.c_str())) != NULL)
  {
    while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL)
    {
      if(string(ent->d_name).compare(".") != 0)
      {
        cout<< ent->d_name << endl;
      }
      else
      {
        string nextDir = string(ent -> d_name);
        nextDir += "\\";

        cout <<  nextDir << endl;

        listDir(nextDir);
      }
    }
  }

  closedir (dir);
}

int main(int param, char **args)
{
  string path = string(args[1]);
  listDir(path);

  return 0;
}
```

I rewrote it so that it uses c++ strings: there's no reason to use C strings here. It works now. There were a number of minor problems, but the most significant was that you didn't specify a size when you went to allocate a char array. This line was the culprit:

```
char *path = new char[]; // bad!
```

If you don't specify a size then the allocator doesn't know how many bytes to request from the heap. Your program didn't require heap allocation because there was no case where data needed to outlive its enclosing lexical block.

Comment: btw there are still a lot of things wrong with this code, a lot of required error checking is lacking.

Comment: also you may need to ```#include <string>``` on some platforms.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator

```
    for(auto& p: fs::recursive_directory_iterator("my_directory"))
        std::cout << p.path() << '\n';
```

Here is an example

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
 
int main()
{
    fs::current_path(fs::temp_directory_path());
    fs::create_directories("sandbox/a/b");
    std::ofstream("sandbox/file1.txt");
    fs::create_symlink("a", "sandbox/syma");
    for(auto& p: fs::recursive_directory_iterator("sandbox"))
        std::cout << p.path() << '\n';
    fs::remove_all("sandbox");
}
```

Output:

```
"sandbox/a"
"sandbox/a/b"
"sandbox/file1.txt"
"sandbox/syma"
```